# Regex to match multiline text between two words including the words

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm editing a dictionary and trying to place every pronunciation tag `[s]...[/s]` after the transcription tag `[c darkslategray]...[/c]`. The problem is that not all the words contain both pronunciation and transcription.

Here's my current regex and the part of the dictionary:

```
(\s\[s\].*?\[\/s\])
(?s)(\s.*?\[c darkslategray\].*?\[\/c\])
```

Then replace with `$2$1` to move tags.

```
contrast
 [s]contra62.wav[/s]
    [b]con·trast[/b]
    [c blue][b]I[/b][/c]
    [m1]({{<vr>}}[p]or[/p] [b]A[/b]{{</vr>}})[c darkslategray]/kənˈtræst, [i]Brit[/i] kənˈtrɑːst/[/c] [p]verb[/p]
    [m2][b]1[/b] \[[p]no obj[/p]\] [b]:[/b] to be different especially in a way that is very obvious[/m]
repellency
 [s]repell01.wav[/s]
    [m1][b]re·pel·len·cy[/b] [c darkslategray]/rıˈpɛlənsi/[/c] [p]noun[/p] \[[p]noncount[/p]\][/m]
    [m2][*][ex]a fabric known for its water [i]repellency[/i][/ex][/*][/m]
labyrinth
 [s]labyri01.wav[/s]
charge card
    [m1][p]noun[/p], [p]pl[/p] [b]⋯ cards[/b] \[[p]count[/p]\]
    [m2][b]:[/b] ↑<<credit card>>[/m]
Antarctic
 [s]gganta10.wav[/s]
    ↑<<antarctic>>
ant
 [s]ant00001.wav[/s]
    [m1][c darkslategray]/ˈænt/[/c] [p]noun[/p], [p]pl[/p] [b]ants[/b] \[[p]count[/p]\]
    [m2][b]:[/b] a kind of small insect that lives in an organized social group[/m]
    [m3][*][ex]a colony of [i]ants[/i] = an [i]ant[/i] colony[/ex][/*][/m]
ring
 [s]ring0004.wav[/s]
```

Regex101 Example: https://regex101.com/r/cG3yK3/5

As you can see, the first two matches are fine, but the third match is not what I'm looking for. It captures the pronunciation of one word and transcription of another word. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You regex should have a negative lookahead to make sure no nested `[s]...[/s]` is matched. Use this regex:

```
(\s\[s\].*?\[\/s\])
(?s)(\s(?:(?!\[s\].*?\[\/s\]).)*?\[c darkslategray\].*?\[\/c\])
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG3yK3/6)